# PDFTron: Filling a form with Scandic letters

Tags: php, encoding, pdftron

I'm trying to write a PHP-script to fill a form with data from an array.

This works mostly fine. Except that PDFTron encodes my strings so that e.g. 'Älli älä jätä' becomes ' lli
l  j t'.

I tried disabling read-only from the text-fields to see if manually writing some text would work - that it did.

I also tested generating the PDF with a different tool (PDFTK) - this too produced a desired PDF with Scandic letters.

```php
<?php
require_once './lib/pdftron/PDFNetPHP.php';

PDFNet::Initialize();

/**
 * @var PDFDoc
 */
$doc = new PDFDoc('./test.pdf');

$field = $doc->GetField('value');
$field->SetValue(utf8_encode('Älli älä jätä'));

$doc->RefreshFieldAppearances();
$doc->FlattenAnnotations();

$buffer = $doc->Save(SDFDoc::e_linearized);

header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($buffer));

echo $buffer;
```

[Link to the PDF-document created with Adobe Indesign 15.1.1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12kvGamP9G39huBIQUez_QhCNtQk308Br/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.
So the problem doesn't seem to be with PDFTron, but with Indesign which embeds a broken font.

When I opened the PDF-document in Adobe Acrobat I was able to edit the properties for the text-field and therefore change the font 'TimesNewRomanPSMT' to 'Times New Roman' which fixed the problem.

Comment: If you answered your own question, which is fine in StackOverflow, mark your question as the answer please.

Comment: The problem seems to be that Indesign doesn't embed fonts that are used in fields. So because I didn't have the font available in my Docker-container it couldn't fill the glyphs.

One way to fix this is the one I mentioned above. A other would be to install fontconfig and configure that to give a replacement font when the glyph is missing.

Comment: It sounds like you have question(s) about InDesign. I would suggest deleting this one, and creating a new question using the adobe-indesign tag